# How to go about checking for expired JWT tokens in API response using redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt, redux-saga

What is the best way to test whether an API has failed due to expiry of JWT token in React (create-react-app), Redux and Redux-Saga?

Currently I'm checking for the response's status code in the API function which looks like the following, (I've written this test at only 1 place):

```
} else if(response.status === 401) {
    return {"success" : false, "unauthenticated": true }
}
```

In sagas, I test it in the following manner:

```
else if(data.unauthenticated) {
    yield put({type: LOGOUT, message: "You are unauthenticated, Please login again!"});
}
```

The problem with the above approach is, I've to write the test in every saga at the end of API calls. I was thinking if it is possible to perform this test only at a single place much like the first code snippet. As I think writing same test at different places only increases boilerplate code which is not good if I have to scale the application.

So, any suggestions on how I should go about it?

Answer (score 2):

You can always make a global interceptor for the axios instance.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
   (response) => response,
   (error) => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
         store.dispatch(
           { type: LOGOUT, message: "You are unauthenticated, Please login again!" },
         );
      }
   },
);
```

**Note**: Remember to import your store to be able to call dispatch.

Comment: Why do you think I use axios?

Comment: @subham is there any other good alternative for axios? `request` maybe? What are you using anyways?

Comment: I think that axios has become the de facto standard in React world for API calls

Comment: and yeah, I use axios only

Comment: @subham Then here you go

Comment: Instead of using interceptor, why can't I just add the LOGOUT dispatch in the first code snippet of my question?

Comment: @subham Of course you can, but you will have to do it in every saga that is auth-sensitive

Comment: I asked this because for some reason the control is not going into the error interceptor callback

Comment: @subham remember it has to be the same instance which you are using for requests.

Comment: It is, that is why I'm so confused

Comment: @subham and it has to be used after declaring axios instance

Comment: Hahahaha, I know that, I'm not so naive